# CodeDeploy pipeline not finding AppSpec.yml - but is clearly available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I've had this running months ago, so I know it works, but have created a new EC2 instance to deploy my code and stuck at the first hurdle.

My Deployment Details runs as follows:

- Application Stop - succeeded
- Download Bundle - succeeded
- BeforeInstall - Failed

Upon looking at the failed event, I get:

> The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at revision-relative path "appspec.yml". The revision was unpacked to directory "C:\ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/57f7ec1b-0452-444e-840c-4deb4566e82d/d-WH9HTZAW0/deployment-archive", and the AppSpec file was expected but not found at path "C:\ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/57f7ec1b-0452-444e-840c-4deb4566e82d/d-WH9HTZAW0/deployment-archive/appspec.yml". Consult the AWS CodeDeploy Appspec documentation for more information at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html

Thing is, if I jump onto my EC2 and copy and paste the full path, sure enough I see the YML file, along with the files that were in a ZIP file within my S3 bucket, so they've been successfully sent to the EC2 and unzipped.

So I'm sure it's not a permissions things, the connection is being clearly made, and the S3 Bucket, CodeDeploy and my EC2 are all happy.

I read various posts on StackOverflow about changing the AppSpec.yml file to "appspec.yml", "AppSpec.yaml", "appspec.yaml", and still nothing works.

Anything obvious to try out?

Answer (score 2):

OK, after a few days back and forth, the solution was incredibly annoying (and embarrassing)...

On my EC2 instance, the "File Name Extensions" was unticked, so my AppSpec.yml was actually AppSpec.yml.txt

IF anyone else has a similar issue, do check this first!!

Comment: where is this option in AWS exactly? CodePipeline or EC2

Answer (score 0):

How are you zipping the file. A lot of times users end up "double-zipping". To check if you unzip the .zip file does it gives you the files or the folder?

When we zip a folder on Windows, it basically creates a folder inside the zip folder and thus, CodeDeploy agent cannot read it. So to zip the artifact, please select all the files and then right click to zip it on the same location. This would avoid creating a new folder inside the zip.